# What is this insect that I found under my bed

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image][image]

Found it under a hotel bed in Las Vegas, what is it? [image]

Comment: That is a cockroach nymph. Don't worry, not a bedbug.

Comment: Added info about the city. Thanks Karl for the info, I started looking when I noticed a lot of what looked like bites on my legs and some on my arms and it reminded me of the time when I had a bedbug problem about 10 years ago. Couldn't find any in the beds though.

Comment: A size scale would be very helpful here

Comment: looks like fragmented body part of a cockroach

Answer (score 1):

It is a Madagascar hissing  cockroach. They are native to Africa, particularly Madagascar. In the [U.S. these roaches only invade homes when accidentally brought in via imported furniture or food](https://www.pestcontrolplans.com/cockroaches/madagascar-hissing-cockroaches/), although some people do keep them as pets.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madagascar_hissing_cockroach[image]

Comment: -1. I don't think you're correct. Please provide additional support for your answer. I agree that the OP's specimen is a roach, but the appearance and size of the OP's specimen do not match a madagascar hissing roach. Further, finding a single, random MHR in Las Vegas is unlikely. Please update your answer with additional pieces of information that more definitively match your ID. Thanks.